# I've had gay sex, how can I ask for forgiveness

Tags: tawba, zina, homosexuality

I'm not GAY because I don't have feelings for mens, I love womens. But I've been Bi-Curious lately and I ended up taking BJ from a guy. We did it 3-4 times. Now I regret it and want to ask for forgiveness. I intend to never do it again. How should I ask for forgiveness from Allah

Answer (score 0):

Just repent to Allah and seek his forgiveness if you all these are met Insha’Allah Allah will forgive you

1. Admit your sin
2. Regret it be remorseful and sincere
3. Promise Allah never to do it again
4. If you can do it undo it for example (stealing)
   DO NOT LOOSE HOPE THATS A MAJOR SIN IN ISLAM TO LOOSE HOPE IN ALLAH’S FORGIVENESS AND HELP
   Please do not lose hope and do righteous deeds and Insha’Allah Allah will forgive you